# autocomplete value ajax not responded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to search autocomplete inputbox with AJAX ,

if i search value with number , ajax respond for sql ,but if i search value with string ,ajax not respond ,

```
function auto_list_peserta() {

    var keyword = $('#listed').text();

        $.ajax({
            url: '../content/act/rekap_peserta.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('.list').show();
                $('.list').html(data);
            }
        });

}
```

here is rekap_peserta.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/this.print.css">
<?
require "../../include/koneksi.php";
$no_urut = $_POST["keyword"];
$sql = mysqli_query($konek,"SELECT * FROM tbl_registrasi,detail_registrasi where detail_registrasi.nama_peserta='$no_urut' AND tbl_registrasi.nama_peserta='$no_urut'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo "<li data-id='$data[nama_peserta]' id='item' onclick='set_item_peserta($data[nama_peserta])'> $data[nama_peserta]</li>";
```

for example I change the query into a search based on numbers, ajax will respond , whereas when I want to find a search based on text , ajax does not respond

Comment: where is your html and rekap_peserta.php ?

Comment: If your Ajax call works with numbers, then the call is good. The problem would probably be in your rekap_peserta.php file. Please post.

Comment: i've edited for my post

Comment: is it possible that your values for `nama_peserta` are only numeric, hence no results when searching for a string?